# What is the easiest way to setup a new public Oxen service node?

Tags: monero-forks, public-node, oxen, oxen-service-node

What is the easiest and fastest way to setup a public Oxen service node?

Comment: Upgrading is simple without doing a full on "apt upgrade". Just do: **apt install oxend oxen-storage-server lokinet**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the guide here as of May 2021:

https://docs.oxen.io/using-the-oxen-blockchain/oxen-service-node-guides/full-service-node-setup-guide

If setting up a brand new Ubuntu 20.04 server, you just need the following commands:

```
sudo curl -so /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/oxen.gpg https://deb.oxen.io/pub.gpg


echo "deb https://deb.oxen.io focal main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oxen.list


sudo apt update


sudo apt install oxen-service-node


oxend status
```

If you want to skip the downloading of the entire blockchain, you can always fetch the entire blockchain from:

https://public.loki.foundation

Just download and replace it directly to: /var/lib/oxen/lmdb

Another alternative is put this in a bash script and run it on a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.4:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo curl -so /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/oxen.gpg https://deb.oxen.io/pub.gpg
echo "deb https://deb.oxen.io focal main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oxen.list
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt upgrade -y
apt install fail2ban magic-wormhole ack-grep oxen-service-node -y
systemctl stop oxen-node
cd /var/lib/oxen/lmdb
rm data.mdb
wget https://public.loki.foundation/loki/data.mdb
chown _loki: data.mdb
sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
echo "/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
```

Comment: Upgrading is simple without doing a full on "apt upgrade". Just do: apt install oxend oxen-storage-server lokinet –